# How do I put multiple texts inside a button?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button that I want to recreate and it looks like this:

[image]

I had already done a part of it by using a normal `Button` and a `drawable` as its background. But how can I recreate the text layout inside the button? I tried putting `TextView`s inside a `ConstraintLayout` inside the `Button` but it did not work.

How do I create such layout that can also be changed programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom view; Set the text elements positioning inside the layout, configure a background to behave with multiple states when `pressed|selected|enabled|disabled`, and finally attach an `onClickListener` to the view;

For the custom view, I used this:

```
public class WrapperPeriodicElement extends ConstraintLayout {

    private TextView textTop;
    private TextView textMiddle;
    private TextView textBottom;

    private String strTextTop;
    private String strTextMiddle;
    private String strTextBottom;

    public WrapperPeriodicElement(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public WrapperPeriodicElement(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.periodic_element, this);

        this.textTop = view.findViewById(R.id.text_top);
        this.textMiddle = view.findViewById(R.id.text_middle);
        this.textBottom = view.findViewById(R.id.text_bottom);

        TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.WrapperPeriodicElement, 0, 0);
        try {
            strTextTop = array.getString(R.styleable.WrapperPeriodicElement_textTop);
            strTextMiddle = array.getString(R.styleable.WrapperPeriodicElement_textMiddle);
            strTextBottom = array.getString(R.styleable.WrapperPeriodicElement_textBottom);
        } finally {
            array.recycle();
        }


        textTop.setText(strTextTop);
        textMiddle.setText(strTextMiddle);
        textBottom.setText(strTextBottom);
    }

    public String getTextTop() {
        return strTextTop;
    }

    public String getTextMiddle() {
        return strTextMiddle;
    }

    public String getTextBottom() {
        return strTextBottom;
    }

    public void setTextTop(String text) {
        this.strTextTop = text;
        textTop.setText(strTextTop);
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    public void setTextMiddle(String text) {
        this.strTextMiddle = text;
        textMiddle.setText(strTextMiddle);
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    public void setTextBottom(String text) {
        this.strTextBottom = text;
        textBottom.setText(strTextBottom);
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

the custom view for this element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/periodic_element_background"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="019" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_middle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Kg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_middle"
        tools:text="Potassium" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

the background for the `periodic_element`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/periodic_element_disabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/periodic_element_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/periodic_element_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/periodic_element_enabled" android:state_enabled="true" />
</selector>
```

in my example, there are only a color inside each item, here the `periodic_element_disabled.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/periodic_element_disabled"/>
</shape>
```

the code inside the main_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Are you made of Cooper and Tellurium?\nBecause you're"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.example.joao.periodicproject.customview.WrapperPeriodicElement
        android:id="@+id/element_cooper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:textBottom="Cooper"
        app:textMiddle="Cu" />

    <com.example.joao.periodicproject.customview.WrapperPeriodicElement
        android:id="@+id/element_telurium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/element_cooper"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:textBottom="Tellurium"
        app:textMiddle="Te"
        app:textTop="52" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="I was going to make a joke about sodium, but..."
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/element_cooper" />

    <com.example.joao.periodicproject.customview.WrapperPeriodicElement
        android:id="@+id/element_sodium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and finally, the `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final WrapperPeriodicElement cooper = findViewById(R.id.element_cooper);
        cooper.setTextTop("29");

        cooper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, cooper.getTextBottom(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        final WrapperPeriodicElement sodium = findViewById(R.id.element_sodium);
        sodium.setTextTop("11");
        sodium.setTextMiddle("Na");
        sodium.setTextBottom("Sodium");

        sodium.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, sodium.getTextBottom(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

here the result:

[image: result];

you can check the code on [github](https://github.com/krllus/PeriodicElementView)

Comment: Thank you for the very good information.
But the Android studio build is old, so it's not working well.
I made a new one separately.
Please refer to the link.
Thank you.
https://github.com/h12sw06/PeriodicElementView

Comment: thats an old project, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

To style a string you can use `Spannable`. It is very powerful and will allow you to do what you want.

For example to make the K with upperscript:

```
SpannableStringBuilder cs = new SpannableStringBuilder("K19");
cs.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

for smaller text you can use `new RelativeSizeSpan(0.5f)` and you can use a new line `\n` to make your text multi-line.

Then just set the Spannable as your button's text.

[Here](https://medium.com/google-developers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568) is a more comprehensive guide.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use a **Button** since this only allows you to use one text. You can make the effect you are looking for by creating a **RelativeLayout** and adding multiple **TextViews** to it and then creating a click listener for the layout. You can pretty much make anything a button by setting a clickListener to it. Change the background of the view to style it how you want as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use for your TextView:

1. android:translationZ="100dp"
2. android:elevation="2dp"

   ```
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

            app:cornerRadius="0dp"
            android:insetTop="0dp"
            android:insetBottom="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/BUTTON1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#d90000"
            android:text="B1"
            android:textSize="50dp" />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:translationZ="100dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).